# MarkLogic CPF not performing an action on document delete

Tags: triggers, marklogic

I am using MarkLogic CPF.

I have configured CPF for the below 3 states

`http://marklogic.com/states/initial`

`http://marklogic.com/states/updated`

`http://marklogic.com/states/deleted`

Everything is working fine when `initial` & `updated` states

but when I delete a document CPF is not executing the configured module.

please find below the pipeline configuration (pasted only for deleted state)

```
<state-transition>
    <annotation>
            when document is deleted in 'abc' collection
    </annotation>
    <state>http://marklogic.com/states/deleted</state>
    <on-success>http://marklogic.com/states/done</on-success>
    <on-failure>http://marklogic.com/states/error</on-failure>
    <execute>
        <condition>
            <module>/MarkLogic/cpf/actions/namespace-condition.xqy</module>
            <options xmlns="/MarkLogic/cpf/actions/namespace-condition.xqy">
                <root-element>head</root-element>
                <namespace>https://www.head.org/Schema/head/hd</namespace>
            </options>
        </condition>
        <action>
            <module>delete-record.xqy</module>
        </action>
    </execute>
</state-transition>
```

CPF is configured for `abc` collection.

When I delete a document with root node as `head` with namespace as `https://www.head.org/Schema/head/hd`

`delete-record.xqy` module is not getting executed.

Please help me to find the issue, If need more detail please let me know.

**Update:**

Complete pipeline configuration

```
<pipeline xmlns="http://marklogic.com/cpf/pipelines">
    <pipeline-name>Combined Search</pipeline-name>
    <pipeline-description>Make a single copy</pipeline-description>
    <success-action>
        <module>/MarkLogic/cpf/actions/success-action.xqy</module>
    </success-action>
    <failure-action>
        <module>/MarkLogic/cpf/actions/failure-action.xqy</module>
    </failure-action>
    <state-transition>
        <annotation>
            on creation
        </annotation>
        <state>http://marklogic.com/states/initial</state>
        <on-success>http://marklogic.com/states/done</on-success>
        <on-failure>http://marklogic.com/states/error</on-failure>
        <execute>
            <condition>
                <module>/MarkLogic/cpf/actions/namespace-condition.xqy</module>
                <options xmlns="/MarkLogic/cpf/actions/namespace-condition.xqy">
                    <root-element>head</root-element>
                    <namespace>https://www.head.org/Schema/head/hd
                    </namespace>
                </options>
            </condition>
            <action>
                <module>create-full-record.xqy</module>
            </action>
        </execute>
    </state-transition>
    <state-transition>
        <annotation>
            on update
        </annotation>
        <state>http://marklogic.com/states/updated</state>
        <on-success>http://marklogic.com/states/done</on-success>
        <on-failure>http://marklogic.com/states/error</on-failure>
        <execute>
            <condition>
                <module>/MarkLogic/cpf/actions/namespace-condition.xqy</module>
                <options xmlns="/MarkLogic/cpf/actions/namespace-condition.xqy">
                    <root-element>head</root-element>
                    <namespace>https://www.head.org/Schema/head/hd
                    </namespace>
                </options>
            </condition>
            <action>
                <module>update-record-biblio.xqy</module>
            </action>
        </execute>
        <execute>
            <condition>
                <module>/MarkLogic/cpf/actions/namespace-condition.xqy</module>
                <options xmlns="/MarkLogic/cpf/actions/namespace-condition.xqy">
                    <root-element>media</root-element>
                    <namespace>https://www.media.org/Schema/Media/md</namespace>
                </options>
            </condition>
            <action>
                <module>update-media.xqy</module>
            </action>
        </execute>
        <execute>
            <condition>
                <module>/MarkLogic/cpf/actions/namespace-condition.xqy</module>
                <options xmlns="/MarkLogic/cpf/actions/namespace-condition.xqy">
                    <root-element>tracking</root-element>
                    <namespace>https://www.tracking.org/Schema/Tracking/tr</namespace>
                </options>
            </condition>
            <action>
                <module>update-tracking.xqy</module>
            </action>
        </execute>
    </state-transition>
    <status-transition>
        <annotation>
            on deletion
        </annotation>
        <status>deleted</status>
        <on-success>http://marklogic.com/states/done</on-success>
        <on-failure>http://marklogic.com/states/error</on-failure>
        <always>true</always>
        <execute>
            <condition>
                <module>/MarkLogic/cpf/actions/namespace-condition.xqy</module>
                <options xmlns="/MarkLogic/cpf/actions/namespace-condition.xqy">
                    <root-element>head</root-element>
                    <namespace>https://www.head.org/Schema/head/hd
                    </namespace>
                </options>
            </condition>
            <action>
                <module>delete-record.xqy</module>
            </action>
        </execute>
    </status-transition>
</pipeline>
```

No action is performed on document creation, updation & deletetion.
Please help me to find the mistakes I am doing.

I have attached two pipelines to the domain.

above one & `Status Change Handling`

**Update:**

Analysis:

I put a log in `namespace-condition.xqy` file.
On deleting a document above file will be called and
When I checked the `fn:doc-available($cpf:document-uri)` it is returning me `false`. which means the doc is already gone (deleted) hence no trigger.

For `status-transition` & `state-transition` it is not working, please help me to understand the mistake and how I can resolve it.

Comment: I think the document is already gone by the time the state condition is evaluated, so you can't use conditions that rely on anything attached to the document (content, properties, collections, etc). I suspect you can only make it depend on uri..

Comment: @grtjn I made few changes as suggested by `mholstege` but still facing some problems, could you please help me on this. I have updated the question. If you need more detail please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

The state names are not in themselves meaningful. If you look at the definitions in the Status Change Handling pipeline you'll see that it happens to set the state to http://marklogic.com/states/initial on a creation (and similarly for an update), but for deletion it doesn't set the state, it runs an action. If you want your own actions in response to a deletion you'll need a status transition, not a state transition.  Something like:

```
<status-transition>
  <annotation>
  Do some extra work.
  </annotation>
  <status>deleted</status>
  <priority>5000</priority>
  <always>true</always>     
  <execute>
    <condition>
        <module>/MarkLogic/cpf/actions/namespace-condition.xqy</module>
        <options xmlns="/MarkLogic/cpf/actions/namespace-condition.xqy">
            <root-element>head</root-element>
            <namespace>https://www.head.org/Schema/head/hd</namespace>
        </options>
    </condition>
    <action>
        <module>delete-record.xqy</module>
    </action>
</execute>
```

The "always" says to do this in addition to the normal deletion processing in the status change handling pipeline.

Comment: On Adding `status-transition` with status `delete`. CPF stopped working for `http://marklogic.com/states/initial` & `http://marklogic.com/states/updated` `state-transitions`. No action is getting triggered.

Comment: I have added the complete pipeline configuration in the question

Comment: I have updated the question. Added the analysis. please help!

Comment: please respond.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the Status Change Handling pipeline attached to your domain? It is the one responsible for handling the status events of creation and update to set those states so that the state transitions can respond.

Comment: Yes 'status change handling' pipeline is attached to the domain.

Comment: To diagnose this kind of thing, enable the CPF trace events (group>diagnostics, type in CPF and you'll get several events enabled) as well as `CPF Condition Invoke`, `CPF Condition Result`, and `CPF Action Invoke`.  This will give you a very chatty blow by blow of what CPF is trying to do. You can also enable `finer` level debugging, which should show you the precommit triggers